# Convert JSX string to JSX expression with .map (React)

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I need to change this data that is passed into a component

```
columns={[{
    name: "Fund Name",
        width: "40%"
    }, {
        name: "Review Date",
        width: "20%"
    }, {
        name: "Company Debt",
        width: "20%"
    }, {
        name: "Alerts",
        width: "10%"
    }, {
        name: "Actions",
        width: "10%",
        options: 'customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => { return (<Options />);'
    }]
}
```

to this inside the component...

```
const columns = [{
            name: "Fund Name",
        }, {
            name: "Review Date"
        }, {
            name: "Company Debt"
        }, {
            name: "Alerts",
        }, {
            name: "Actions",
            options: {
                customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
                    return ( <Options /> );
                }
            }
        }
    }];
```

Basically I've got this far....

```
let columns = this.props.columns.map((item, key) =>
   { name: item.name }
);
```

This obviously isn't right but I'm not sure how to say that columns needs to be an array of the data in the .map function.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eval` keyword to *convert strings to JS expressions*

```js
let columns = this.props.columns.map(item =>
   item.options 
    ? ({ ...item, options: eval(item.options) })
    : item
);
```

But there is one problem though. Babel cannot transpile the output of `eval` since it's generated in runtime. So you must convert JSX to normal JS expressions that doesn't need transpilation.

So you code must be like this

```js
const columns = [{
  name: "Actions",
  options: {
    customBodyRender: '(value, tableMeta, updateValue) => { return React.createElement(Options, null); }'
      // or 
    customBodyRender: '(value, tableMeta, updateValue) => { return /*#__PURE__*/_react.default.createElement(Options, null); }'
      // Depends on your babel configurations
}]
```

Comment: Could you please help with my Edit as well. It is a similar problem but can't get it to work.

Comment: Honestly it should be another question. Because both are different and in future someone might face the problem and they won't be able find the answer for this. So ask a new question and let me know

Comment: Ok I have posted another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60923904/creating-nested-array-of-items-using-map-and-react
Thanks