# How to create Material-UI nested style object from array using map in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have some prop data that gets passed in like this

```
columns={
  [
    {
      name: "Fund Name",
      width: "40%"
    },
    {
      name: "Review Date",
      width: "20%"
    },
    {
      name: "Company Debt",
      width: "20%"
    },
    {
      name: "Alerts",
      width: "10%"
    }
  ];
}
```

I need it to look like this...

```
const localTheme = {
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
      root: {
        "&:nth-child(1)": {
          width: "40%"
        },
        "&:nth-child(2)": {
          width: "20%"
        },
        "&:nth-child(3)": {
          width: "20%"
        },
        "&:nth-child(4)": {
          width: "10%"
        },
        "&:nth-child(5)": {
          width: "10%"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying this...

```
let rowWidths = this.props.columns.map((item, key) => ({
  "&:nth-child(+key+)": {
    width: item.width
  }
}));

const localTheme = {
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
      root: {
        rowWidths
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this obviously doesn't work. Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: What is `'&:nth-child(+key+)'` ? Did you mean `'&:nth-child(' + key + ')'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Object.assign, spread syntax and the string literals to get the desired result

```js
let columns=[
{
    name: "Fund Name",
    width: "40%"
}, {
    name: "Review Date",
    width: "20%"
}, {
    name: "Company Debt",
    width: "20%"
}, {
    name: "Alerts",
    width: "10%",
}]

let rowWidths = columns.map((item, key) =>
        ({
            [`&:nth-child(${key})`]: {
                width: item.width
            }
        })
    );

const localTheme = {
        overrides: {
            MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
                root: Object.assign({}, ...rowWidths)
            }
       }
  } 
  
  console.log(localTheme, rowWidths);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to write it in one line

> transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.

```
  const root = Object.fromEntries(
    columns.map((x, idx) => [`&:nth-child(${idx + 1})`, { width: x.width }])
  );
```

Demo try it in-text:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: "Fund Name",
    width: "40%"
  },
  {
    name: "Review Date",
    width: "20%"
  },
  {
    name: "Company Debt",
    width: "20%"
  },
  {
    name: "Alerts",
    width: "10%"
  }
];

const root = Object.fromEntries(
  columns.map((x, idx) => [`&:nth-child(${idx + 1})`, { width: x.width }])
);

const localTheme = {
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
      root: root
    }
  }
}

console.log(localTheme);
```

Comment: Turns out this doesn't work with IE which is crucial for me.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want to do is convert `'&:nth-child(+key+)'` to `'&:nth-child(1)'` , `'&:nth-child(2)'` and so on right.

To use JS expression or dynamic string as `keys` in an object you need to use them within square brackets `[]`. I'm using reduce instead of map since the output must be objects instead of array

```js
let rowWidths = this.props.columns.reduce((acc, item, key) =>
  ({
    ...acc,
    [`&:nth-child(${key})`]: {
       width: item.width
     }
   }),
   {}
);
```

And use spread operator to spread them open in localTheme

```js
const localTheme = {
  overrides: {
    MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
      root: {
        ...rowWidths 
      }
   }
```